# Routing does not work - angularjs - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, route-provider, angularjs-injector

I am new to angular js. I was just writing some sample application and I ran into problem with routes. 
I am using cdn for angular

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I created a html partial/file and wanted to link it to the index.html.I added the 
`<ng-view></ng-view>` in the index.html and also the following code in the html for routing

```
angular.module("sample", []).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
            {
                templateUrl: "/partials/list.html"
            });
});
```

But I am getting an Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=enterprise&p1=Erro…s.org%2F1.2.13%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%......2)

Also, I tried downloading angular-route.js and adding ngRoute as dependency, but it still does not work.

```
angular.module("enterprise", ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
            {
                templateUrl: "/partials/list.html"
            });
});
```

I have downloaded various versions of angularjs but I am stuck with the same error. Any idea has to why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that both scripts are loaded before your above code runs? In your console your should be able to run `angular.module('ngRoute')` and get back an object if it was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.module("enterprise", ['ngRoute']).config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
            {
                templateUrl: "/partials/list.html"
            });
}]);
```

Let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the slash from templateUrl like this?

```
 templateUrl: "partials/list.html"
```

Also, could you verify that you have set ng-app somewhere in the html and the template exists at the proper location (partials/list.html)?